# Order the log of my VPN, I have list of: username, date+hour, (in or out) to VPN

Tags: sql, postgresql

Event: "in" connect VPN , "out" disconnect VPN

```
create table test(
  Username text,
  Date timestamp,
  Event text
);

insert into test values
('Luis', to_timestamp('30/08/2022 1:00am', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MIam'), 'in'),
('Maria', to_timestamp('30/08/2022 1:05am', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MIam'), 'in'),
('Luis', to_timestamp('30/08/2022 1:30am', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MIam'), 'out'),
('Jorge', to_timestamp('30/08/2022 1:50am', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MIam'), 'in'),
('Carla', to_timestamp('30/08/2022 3:40am', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MIam'), 'in'),
('Carla', to_timestamp('30/08/2022 4:30am', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MIam'), 'out'),
('Maria', to_timestamp('30/08/2022 6:10am', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MIam'), 'out'),
('Luis', to_timestamp('30/08/2022 7:00am', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MIam'), 'in'),
('Luis', to_timestamp('30/08/2022 8:00am', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MIam'), 'out');

select * from test;

| Username    |     Date           | Event |
------------------------------------------------
| Luis        | 30/08/2022 1:00am  |  in   |
| Maria       | 30/08/2022 1:05am  |  in   |
| Luis        | 30/08/2022 1:30am  |  out  |
| Jorge       | 30/08/2022 1:50am  |  in   |
| Carla       | 30/08/2022 3:40am  |  in   |
| Carla       | 30/08/2022 4:30am  |  out  |
| Maria       | 30/08/2022 6:10am  |  out  |
| Luis        | 30/08/2022 7:00am  |  in   |
| Luis        | 30/08/2022 8:00am  |  out  |
```

I try to get:

```
| User   |     DateStartVPN     |    DateFinishVPN   |
----
| Luis   |   30/08/2022 1:00am  |  30/08/2022 1:30am |
| Maria  |   30/08/2022 1:05am  |  30/08/2022 6:10am |
| Jorge  |   30/08/2022 1:50am  |  30/08/2022 5:30am |
| Carla  |   30/08/2022 3:40am  |  30/08/2022 4:30am |
| Luis   |   30/08/2022 7:00am  |  30/08/2022 8:00am |
```

I try something like

```
Select user,
       date as DateStartVPN,
       (select min(date) from table where date> date) DateFinishVPN as
from TABLE
where Event = 'in'
```

but I only get null

Comment: I'd expect a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Your original query is ok, but you need to reference your outer table:

> ```
> Select 
>   Username, 
>   Date as DateStartVPN, 
>   (select min(Date) 
>   from test 
>   where Username=t.Username 
>   and date > t.date
>   and Event='out') DateFinishVPN
> from test t where Event = 'in';
> ```
>
> ```
> username | datestartvpn        | datefinishvpn      
> :------- | :------------------ | :------------------
> Luis     | 2022-08-30 01:00:00 | 2022-08-30 01:30:00
> Maria    | 2022-08-30 01:05:00 | 2022-08-30 06:10:00
> Jorge    | 2022-08-30 01:50:00 | null               
> Carla    | 2022-08-30 03:40:00 | 2022-08-30 04:30:00
> Luis     | 2022-08-30 07:00:00 | 2022-08-30 08:00:00
> ```

While your original query works, I suggest you to look into [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) for this kind of tasks. With window functions, you can process groups of data without doing self-joins or using subqueries, which are not always optimal. E.g., with window functions something like this would work for you:

> ```
> select 
>   Username as "User", 
>   EventDate as "DateStartVpn", 
>   NextEventDate as "DateFinishVpn" 
> from (
> select
>   Username,
>   Date EventDate,
>   Event,
>   lead(event) over(partition by Username order by Date) as NextEvent,
>   lead(Date) over(partition by Username order by Date) as NextEventDate
> from test
> ) t where t.event != 'out'
> order by EventDate, User;
> ```
>
> ```
> User  | DateStartVpn        | DateFinishVpn      
> :---- | :------------------ | :------------------
> Luis  | 2022-08-30 01:00:00 | 2022-08-30 01:30:00
> Maria | 2022-08-30 01:05:00 | 2022-08-30 06:10:00
> Jorge | 2022-08-30 01:50:00 | null               
> Carla | 2022-08-30 03:40:00 | 2022-08-30 04:30:00
> Luis  | 2022-08-30 07:00:00 | 2022-08-30 08:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b2ff9c4dac23bcb10d6e94856a916865&hide=1)*